# The null-coalescing operator and throw

Tags: c#, throw, null-coalescing-operator

I've just noticed that when using throw with the null-coalescing operator, you cannot just use the keyword "throw" on its own, an exception must be included with it. The following code demonstrates what I mean:

```
try
{
   return GetName();
}
catch (NameNotFoundException ex)
{
    string name = GetOtherName();
    // this is legal
    return name ?? throw ex;
    // whereas this is not
    return name ?? throw;
}
```

Is there any reason for this? Would it be because `throw;` doesn't constitute an expression, or is there more to it?

Comment: I guess that with only throw, you are passing the excpetion to some next code and stacking the excpetion (not stopping there). On the other hand, throw ex, forces the app to stop there and handle the exception. When you combine it with return, there is not "next" code so, the compiler needs "something" to handle. ALSO, the right side of coalescing cannot be null...

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues "the right side of coalescing cannot be null" - this is not true: `return name ?? null;` compiles fine.

Comment: ...correct...my mistake. What its true is the righte side of coalescing must be a non-nullable type. My applogies.

Comment: IIRC this was proposed but never implemented. I don't think there was any major reason other than that it's a rare case.

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/1789

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.0/throw-expression

a throw expression consists of the throw keyword followed by a null_coalescing_expression where the null_coalescing_expression

> must denote a value of the class type System.Exception, of a class
> type that derives from System.Exception or of a type parameter type
> that has System.Exception (or a subclass thereof) as its effective
> base class. If evaluation of the expression produces null, a
> System.NullReferenceException is thrown instead

`return name ?? throw;` does not satisfy this condition as only the throw expression would be allowed here, not a throw statement.

At least that's how I read this.